# JavaScript search function not showing the results properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

The HTML table has `colspan` and `rowspan` attributes, where the Javascript search function is not working properly, and its just displaying only one row in the case of ROWSPAN is 2 or 3.

This is the HTML code

```
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" class="form-control" 
    placeholder="Search here..." style="width: 100%; padding: 10px 10px">
<br>
<table class="table" style="text-align: left; width: 100%;"
    border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
    <thead>
        <tr class="thead header">
            <th style="font-weight: bold; text-align: center;">Sl.No</th>
            <th style="font-weight: bold; text-align: center; width: 
            45%;">Heading
                1
            </th>
            <th style="font-weight: bold; text-align: center;">Heading
                2
            </th>
            <th style="font-weight: bold; text-align: center;">Heading
                3
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="myTable">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="3">1</td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="3">HEAD 1</td>
            <td style="text-align: left;">some content1</td>
            <td style="text-align: left;">some content1.1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align: left;">some content2</td>
            <td style="text-align: left;">some content2.1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align: left;">some content3</td>
            <td style="text-align: left;">some content3.1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="2">2</td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="2">HEAD 2</td>
            <td>some content4</td>
            <td>some content4.1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>some content5</td>
            <td>some content5.1</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This is the JavaScript code for the search function

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {

        var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();

        $("#myTable tr").filter(function() {

            $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)

        });

    });

});
```

[JSFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/ndw805b4/4/)

Comment: If it's not working properly please provide information on how you wish it to work. What is the expected end result?

Comment: why you have this in your `input` element - `onkeyup="myFunction()"` since you have no function for this and you are using jQuery to be aware of the `keyup` event

Comment: Since the targeted element isn't being specified, it will always look for the first matching element, which means you will have to type the exact search string to match your desired search in this case. Without specifying the elements, you can't target your desired element in the search.

Comment: Kindly check in the given fiddle link.  the table tr has colspan=1 and rowspan = 3 , where you search for the result data it will display only the top row of tr not the other two

Comment: You need to specify by column you want to search

Answer (score 0):

jquery filter's function argument needs return value(Boolean) for filtering condition. but you didn't return anything. check this link http://api.jquery.com/filter/#filter-function

Answer (score 0):

First of all your table structure is wrong. Hence the code `$("#myTable tr")` returns an array of 5 instead of 2.

Furthermore you should use `$("#myTable > tr")` to get the immediate children and from that filter out the unwanted rows.

**Note**

a table cannot have `tr` and `td` adjacent elements. a `td` should always be wrapped by a `tr`. Please update the table syntax and update the question to provide a better answer.